# How to set option's selected flag in Angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular

A have an Angular component that represents a question with a `<select>` to choose one of the possible answers.

I want to set one of the options to `selected` state based on application URL parameters.

Also, the question component is generated dynamically via component factory.

Here is where I'm trying to set `selected` with `ng-selected` (`question.component.html`):

```
  <select>
    <option>Choose...</option>
    <ng-template ngFor let-option [ngForOf]="data.options">
      <option value="{{option.value}}" ng-selected="option.value === urlAnswer">
        {{option.text}}
      </option>
    </ng-template>
  </select>
```

Here is `question.component.ts` important part of code

```
export class QuestionComponent {
  @Input() data: any;
  @Input() urlAnswer: any;
}
```

And here is where I create the component in the parent component (`poll.component.ts`) after I got poll structure from the service:

```
this.pollSubscription = this.pollService.pollLoaded.subscribe((dataFromServer: any) => {
  const viewContainerRef = this.elementsHost.viewContainerRef;
  viewContainerRef.clear();
  const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(QuestionComponent);
  const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  (<QuestionComponent>componentRef.instance).data = dataFromServer.questionData;
  (<QuestionComponent>componentRef.instance).urlAnswer = this.answerFromRouterParams;
});
```

Everything works fine except for ng-selected thing and I can't get why.
Any ideas what needs to be fixed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<option value="{{option.value}}" [selected]="option.value === urlAnswer">
    {{option.text}}
</option>
```

Comment: Nice! Could you accept the answer, so that other people could see that this works?